# Why might not work in github exclude in maven-surefire-plugin?

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

normal settings, everything works locally, but exclude does not work in github. skipTests works correctly. But I only need to skip one integration test so that it stays in failesave. And is there any way to do this without using exclude?

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.maven.plugins maven-surefire-plugin 2.19.1   **/TestClass.java

I use the following command to run tests:

mvn test -Dtest=ITest

For some reason, the surefire plugin is not skipping the test.

You should use skipTests instead of exclude.

Comment: Thanks. mvn test -D test=!**/*IT*